# Webdriver/BeautifulSoup Getting my program to check if part of a string exists on the webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am writing a bot that purchases items automatically. The current way I am going about this is I am putting the product info in a dictionary titled INFO, and referencing it whenever I need a specific product/color/etc.
Currently my code (specifically in findProduct()) checks to see if the index in temp_tuple is the same as INFO['product'] for instance.

In my case, I look for a product and my code returns an error because there is a space at the end of some of the names, and my code cannot handle that.

However, I want to modify it to is check whether or not the string is on the webpage so that way my code runs even with that extra space.

Enough of my code that works as it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
import requests
import bs4 as bs
from splinter import Browser
import helpers
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from config import INFO
def __init__(self, **info):
        self.base_url = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/'
        self.shop = 'shop/all/'
        self.checkout = 'checkout/'
        self.info = info





class supremeBot(object):

def __init__(self, **info):
    self.base_url = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/'
    self.shop = 'shop/all/'
    self.info = info

def initializeBrowser(self):
    driverz = self.info["driver"]
    path = helpers.get_driver_path(driver)
    if driverz == "geckodriver":
        self.b = Browser()
    elif driverz == "chromedriver":
        executable_path = {"executable_path": path}
        self.b = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)


#This looks for the product based on what the category is 
def findProduct(self):
    category =  str(INFO['category'])
    source = requests.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/"+category).text
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    temp_link = []
    temp_tuple = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        temp_tuple.append((link['href'], link.text))
    for i in temp_tuple:
        if i[1] == INFO['product'] or i[1] == INFO['color']: # <------------ I want this to recognize a partial string
            temp_link.append(i[0])
            #print(temp_link)

    #This creates end of the final link
    self.final_link = list(
        set([x for x in temp_link if temp_link.count(x) == 2]))[0]

        #Concatenates the previous link w/ the website
    link = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com'+str(self.final_link)
    driver.get(link)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')


'''
BOT = supremeBot(**INFO)
BOT.findProduct()
order()
'''
BOT = supremeBot(**INFO)

found_product = False
counter = 1
max_iter = 5
while not found_product and counter < max_iter:
    found_product = BOT.findProduct()
    print("We tried ",counter," times.")  
    counter +=1
    if found_product:
        print('Couldn\'t find it')
        continue
    else:
        print('found it')
    order()
INFO = {
    "driver": "chromedriver",
    "product": "Supreme®/MLB New Era®", # "Big Duffle Bag " is an example of a product that has the space after it
    "color": "Navy",
    "category": "hats",
    "size": "Medium",
    "namefield": "Bucky McNuts",
    "emailfield": "email@email.com",
    "phonefield": "(555)555-5555",
    "addressfield": "321 St",
        }
```

In this case, if you were to replace Supreme®/MLB New Era® with "Big Duffle Bag " you'll see the code doesn't run if you removed the space after the word bag.

If anybody could help I would really appreciate it!

Comment: If you want to check if a certain string exists on a webpage, you could search the page source which is easy to obtain with selenium. You could alternatively try to find an element that contains your text using XPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this check for partial string:

```
if "part" in "partstring":
   print("the word 'part' is within 'partsting'")
```

Possible use here:

```
if INFO['product'] in i[1].lower() or INFO['color'] in i[1].lower():
  #do something
```

The `.lower()` is to make sure the text on the site is lower case